# Утечка памяти в Python3.4+Flask+Celery+Gevent+[Flask-]SQLAlchemy+Psycopg2

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, celery

Имеем следующий стек: Python3.4+Celery+Gevent+SQLAlchemy+Psycopg2. Запускаем планировщик:

`$ celery beat -A some_module -l info`

который каждые 10-15 секунд кладет в очередь задачу, и воркер:

`$ celery worker -c 1000 -P gevent -l info -A some_module`

Все работает, как надо, но после пары дней аптайма, процесс сжирает всю имеющуюся на машине память. Может есть у кого-нибудь идеи, как это побороть или найти узкое место?

Comment: возможно вам поможет это https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17541452/celery-does-not-release-memory/17561747#17561747

Comment: Надо код смотреть, возможно у вас где то память течет.
Смущает ваш параметр 
```
-c, --concurrency <concurrency>
Number of child processes processing the queue. The default is the number of CPUs availableon your system.
```
На сколько я понимаю вы запускаете 1000 процессов. Попорбуйте уменьшить до 10 или до количества ядер в системе.

Comment: то что celery текет у них в документации написано